# How to send POST request to API using APP INVENTOR?

Tags: python, post, request, app-inventor

I'm trying to sent a POST-Request, with App Inventor on a button click to my python program, in that case to log in my app. But I always get code 403 and don't know why. To host the API I'm using Django.

That's the App Inventor Code for my APP:

[image: App Inventor Code1]

And that's my current python code, so for example I want to get the `api_key`, using `request.POST['api_key]`:

[image: Python Code]

And that's finally the log, in this case I'm using the Django testserver with anaconda (pip):

[image: Logfile Console]

That're every combination from code I tried, but nothing worked.

[image: AppInventor Code2]

[image: AppInventor Code3]

I searched even on Stack Overflow, Google or AppInventor itself, but there wasn't any solution for my problem.

Comment: it is not a good idea to send a password as pain text to a server... send a password hash instead... see also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=password+hash... my tools extension offers hash methods for App Inventor https://puravidaapps.com/tools.php

Answer (score 1):

I proofed it and found the mistake. The problem was the missing csrf_token. I only added

```
from django.http import JsonResponse 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt 
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST 
import json 

@csrf_exempt 
@require_POST 

def xxx():
```

and it works perfectly.